Why am I not able to go this user's profile via a comment they posted?
While I was going through this question, I noticed a comment by the OP where the username was black in colour instead of the usual turquoise. I tried visiting the user's profile page by clicking on it, but it didn't work as it should usually. I have seen this happen for deleted users, but I am encountering such a situation for an existing user for the first time on PSE. What is going on here?

According to the timeline, the question was migrated from Math.SE to Physics.SE when the OP hadn't had an account here.

Andrew T. hit the nail on the head. When we migrate a question to another site and the user doesn't yet have a user profile on that site, we don't automatically create one, but do try to leave enough bread crumbs so we can restore the migrated posts into the user profile when (or if) they create one on the new site.
Historically, comments have not been supported in this process so they just appear unlinked to an account.
Incidentally, we're currently working through rolling out a way that comment authors would get migrated going forward.  But won't apply to historical migrations anyway (because the data isn't there to associate)
